# save an audio file to a newly created folder - android development

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android app and part of it records audio.
My code works fine and it saves the recorded audio in the SD card using the following code:

```
String mediaFile = null;
mediaFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myRecordings.mp3";
```

But I want to create a folder with the app name and be able to save recorded audio to that folder.
Can someone tell me how to do that? I succeeded in creating the folder but I don't know how to move the mediaFile in there:

```
String newFolder = "/FolderName";
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);
myNewFolder.mkdir();
mediaFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myRecordings.mp3"
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add that folder to the path. Like this:

```
String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
String newFolder = "FolderName";
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);
myNewFolder.mkdir();
mediaFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
  + sep + newFolder + sep + "myRecordings.mp3";
```

Comment: Great @AmandaSlayer! You should mark the answer as accepted, to signal that the question has been solved. Good luck with your app!